# Wifi stopped working

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu

I'm new to linux, I've installed Lubuntu in an old laptop last thursday and I've been having quite a good time with the system. But last night while I was using it as normal the wifi suddenly stopped working and I couldn't manage get it back on.
The wifi icon is there but it doesn't show any network available.

Here some common outputs:

```
    rfkill list
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Accton Technology Corporation AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [1113:c822]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k

dmesg | grep ath
[   36.020507] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[   36.020521] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   36.020530] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   36.020534] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[   39.324340] ath9k 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan1
```

Someone pls help

Comment: *Hard blocked: yes* means that probably you used the hardware switch (a specific button, key or key combo) and turned it off.